# Solving this set of quadratic equations

Tags: analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-equations

I have a set of quadratic equations of the form:

\begin{equation*}
2S_0q_0(q_0S_0 + q_1S_1 + ...... + q_iS_n)+k_0 = 0  \\
2S_1q_1(q_0S_0 + q_1S_1 + ...... + q_iS_n)+k_1 = 0  \\
\vdots \\ 
2S_nq_n(q_0S_0 + q_1S_1 + ...... + q_nS_n)+k_n = 0  \\
\end{equation*}

We have $n$ equations and $n$ variables $q_0,q_1,q_2.....q_n$. The $k$ and $S$ values are constants.

How can I analytically reach a solution for this system?

Comment: This is unclear; are $S_0(q_0)$, $S_1(q_1)$, etc., values of functions evaluated at $q_0$, $q_1$, etc., or is that meant to be a product of the cosntant $S_0$ and the constant $q_0$, etc.? Also, don't use asterisks for products; use juxtaposition.

Comment: Where are the equal signs?

Comment: Sorry. Had to edit it a few times. Would love to have math preview of the question while asking it.

Comment: Do you mean $q_n S_n$ (instead of $q_i S_n$) at the end of the parenthesized sums in the first two equations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Set $X = q_0S_0 + q_1S_1 + \dots + q_n S_n$ and add up all the equations.

Comment: Thanks. I should have seen that !!!